# Redux-observable POST ajax request never sends the network request

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have this [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/) epic that `POST`s a json body to my backend, but it never actually gets so far as to send the actual network request. It uses [Rx.DOM.Request.post(url, [body])](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/rxjs_bindings/dom/ajax/post.html) (I think? please view my imports to confirm). I can verify that the network request never makes it out of my app, let alone hits my backend:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import 'redux-observable'
import {
  UPLOAD_IMAGE,
  UPLOAD_IMAGE_FULFILLED,
  UPLOAD_IMAGE_REJECTED,
  UPLOAD_PRODUCT,
  uploadImageFulfilled,
  uploadImageRejected,
  uploadProductFulfilled,
  uploadProductRejected
} from './addForm.action'
import {
  updateAlertModalIsOpen,
  updateAlertModalMessage,
  updateAlertModalTitle
} from '../alert-modal/alertModal.action'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3'
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax'

export const uploadProductEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(UPLOAD_PRODUCT)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      ajax.post(
        'http://192.168.20.3:4000/products', 
        action.payload,
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    })
    .map(response => uploadProductFulfilled(response))
    .catch(error => Observable.of(uploadProductRejected(error)))
```

It gets invoked by a button press:

```
      onPress={() => {
       let product = {
              "name": props.name,
              "brand": props.brand,
              "description": props.description,
              "image": "fakeUrl"
          }

        props.uploadProduct(JSON.stringify(product))
```

this is the contents of `action` object in the above epic:

```
payload: "{"name":"v","brand":"v","description":"v","image":"fakeUrl"}"
type: "UPLOAD_PRODUCT"
```

Is it because my json is using all double quotes with no escapes?

I can verify the line of code in the epic that performs the ajax post does run when pressing the button, and the on the first button press it ends up dispatching the `uploadProductRejected(error)`, without even making the network request, and where error that gets dispatched in the `uploadProductRejected` action is just `{ }` and on subsequent button presses it never even dispatches a rejected or fulfilled action.

Any idea why it is rejected, and why it never even attempts to make the network request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

btw--the documentation you point to for [`Rx.DOM.Request`](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/rxjs_bindings/dom/ajax/post.html) is for v4 of RxJS, but your code is using v5. Documentation for v5 is [located here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) however `Observable.ajax` is [not yet documented](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#creation-operators) unfortunately but it's pretty close to the v4 version and has a mostly obvious API.

---

Regarding your code, there are a couple housekeeping things we need to do first.

You probably shouldn't put the `map` and `catch` outside on the top-level Observable. If you do, any errors inside your `mergeMap` are allowed to propagate out and reach the `action$.ofType`, meaning your epic will terminate because you catch the error and instead switch from the errored out top-level chain to `Observable.of(uploadProductRejected(error))`.

Instead, you want to isolate your Observables by placing that logic inside the `mergeMap`:

```
export const uploadProductEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(UPLOAD_PRODUCT)
    .mergeMap(action => {
      ajax.post(
        'http://192.168.20.3:4000/products', 
        action.payload,
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      )
        .map(response => uploadProductFulfilled(response))
        .catch(error => Observable.of(uploadProductRejected(error)))
    });
```

While this is just normal RxJS, in redux-observable this is particularly important since you don't want your epic to terminate when one request fails. This is described [in the docs here](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/ErrorHandling.html). If this is confusing, I recommend taking some time to fully understand how Observable chains work. Besides reading documentation and tutorials (which are helpful), also experiment in a REPL like jsbin.

---

Now that we have that out of the way, to truly solve your problem you need to look at what the actual error message is that you caught and emitted as `uploadProductRejected()`.

Although you didn't provide it, I can guess based on your code that it is something like:

> TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. at subscribeToResult

It would also include a stack trace, which should first point to something like `MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub`, which means it's the `mergeMap` operator that is throwing this error. If we look at your usage of `mergeMap` we can see that in fact we are not returning anything! Since you're using an arrow function with **curly braces** that means you need to have an explicit `return`.

```
export const uploadProductEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(UPLOAD_PRODUCT)
    .mergeMap(action => { // <--------------------------- whoops!
      ajax.post(
        'http://192.168.20.3:4000/products', 
        action.payload,
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    })
```

You probably meant to use an arrow function without curly braces, so that it has an implicit return.

Comment: Thanks for explaining things in a very easy to understand way!